# Is a closed convex set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ equal to the closure of its interior?

Tags: general-topology

I have seen similar questions relating the interior of a convex set equal to the interior of its closure. However, I can't find anything that says if $E$ is a closed convex set, then $E = \overline{int E}$. If anyone would be willing to help me sketch a proof of this I would really appreciate it.

I would like to say that this is a simple as noticing that $int E$ is the set $E \setminus bd E$, therefore its closure is to re apply the boundary, but I don't think this is a sound argument.

Edit: Sorry, I should have added the assumption that the convex set has non empty interior.

Comment: There is a theorem wich states that a compact convex set is the convex hull of its extreme points. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem

Comment: @ Andre can you provide a link to this theorem? One step ahead of me haha.

Comment: I just added the link. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

A closed line segment in $\Bbb R^n$ with $n\ge 2$ is a closed convex set with empty interior, so it cannot be the closure of its interior. For $n\ge 1$ a singleton set (a set consisting of a single point) is a counterexample.

Comment: Is there a counterexample that has nonempty interior?

Comment: @Nishant: I suspect not, but I’ve not tried seriously to prove it.